# Which is good for Video Processing applications opencv or matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv

I am working on Multiple Object Tracking algorithms. Which tool is most suited to develop my own algorithm OpenCV or Matlab ?

Comment: First implement on MATLAB, as it would be easier to debug. When the implementation is finalized, port it to OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is a faster way to develop algorithms and testing existing systems. However, when it comes down to producing a commercial and portable application you need open source libraries like openCV. Especially some heavy weight algorithms like object tracking can be quite slow in Matlab while openCV has optimized builtin methods and algorithms about your subject already

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with OpenCV for quite some time and I have to say it is a great tool. The new documentation is much, much better than the old one and the ease of opening multiple camera streams is awesome. I have no experience with Matlab so by bias is pretty high.

OpenCV can be used with many different languages (Again, I don't know about Matlab) including C, C++ and Python. I have found that the Python interface is really nice as they use Numpy arrays for manipulating data.

Here is a simple example of some Python code some students wrote to track both white Frisbees and rectangular targets.
https://github.com/Team3574/2013VisionCode